# How to prevent Xcode Archive from including my sub projects' Products?

Tags: xcode, mac-app-store

I am trying to build an app with Xcode 10.2.1 and submit it to the Mac App Store.

However, when I archive it, the Organizer does not show my app's version, and the button on the right is titled "Distribute Content" and not "Distribute App" as it should. And I won't get to option to upload the to Store.

When I export to disk, I see that the archive contains a "Products" folder at the top level, and then multiple folders containing all my included sub projects, containing frameworks and helper tools.

As all these are already linked into the app, I don't need to have them also in the Archive as separate items, of course. And I suspect that's the reason why I can't submit the app from the Organizer.

If I make a regular build, the build/Release folder only contains the app, not the other products.

What could I be doing wrong, i.e. how to I prevent the products from the sub projects to be included in the main project's Archive?

I need to keep these other projects inside the main project so that I do not forget to build them when I change code in one of their source files.

#### Here's some information of how I set this up:

The main project shows the other projects in the left browser when I open its disclosure triangle.

The main project's target's **Build Phases** also lists these sub project's targets.

The **Scheme**, under **Build**, shows the main project's target, with the other targets are children. All checkboxes are ticked.

The **Scheme**, under **Archive**, selects the Release build config.

#### Work-around

For now, I build the app regularly, then use the cmdline tool as follows to create a pkg file that I then upload with Apple's Application Loader:

`productbuild --component "MyApp.app" /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: My Name" "MyApp.pkg"`

The fact that this works suggests that my app is fine. It's just the added products that are causing the trouble for the Organizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/tclementdev/status/1159113555590995969?s=20), the solution is to set "Skip Install" to YES in every sub project's Build Settings.